# How to convert a generic List<MyClass> to IList<System.Type>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, generics

I'm trying to convert a List that contains Products into a List of Type to return to another method. This is how my method looks like:

```
public IList<Type> GetProducts()
{
    var products = new List<Products>()
    {
        new Products { ID="1",Name="Soap",Price="200"},
        new Products { ID="2",Name="Trouser",Price="300"},
        new Products { ID="3",Name="Shirt",Price="400"}
    }.ToList();

    return products;
}
```

> **Error:** *Giving me an error saying cannot convert a List of Products into List of System.Type.*

Can someone please give me an approach to solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Product` is descendant of `object`, not `Type`.

Comment: yes, but I have to return a T type List

Comment: You might as well return: new List<Type> { typeof(Products) } as it is the only type available in the list.

Comment: #Uno , i have tried your way as well gives me the same error - "Products is a variable but use like a Type"

Comment: Question: in your `IList<Type>` have you defined `Type` somewhere else in your project?  eg `MyNamespace.Type` ?   Or are you expecting a list of `System.Type` to be returned by the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit midified version of answer by @ice-jovanoski. It uses "**products.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToList()**"

```
    public static IList<Type> GetProducts()
    {
        var products = new List<Products>()
        {
            new Products { ID="1",Name="Soap",Price="200"},
            new Products { ID="2",Name="Trouser",Price="300"},
            new Products { ID="3",Name="Shirt",Price="400"}
        }.ToList();

        return products.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToList();            
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to do .ToList() twice in GetProducts. Doing it only once in return statement should be good enough.

Comment: @Dayan it's really unclear why you would need this. What is the calling code going to do with a `List<Type> { typeof(Product), typeof(Product), typeof(Product) }`?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's review what you've written:

1. `public IList<Type> GetProducts()` basically means that you'll return a list of **Type** objects, but in the method's body you basically say `return new List<Products>;` which you obviously cannot do because it's contradicting with the methods signature. You can rather `return products.Select(x=>typeof(x)).ToList();` which will select the types of the objects inside the list.
2. Why would you want to do that? You're creating list of the same type, **Products**, and the returned list would contain all the same objects (type of Products).
3. Can you be more specific, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: what i simply wants here is to send a T type list a to another method. Same way i used the products in my example, i have other classes, i need to use them as well.

Comment: `products.Select(x=>typeof(x)).ToList();` you can to that and get a list of the types of any list with objects.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I tried it out. gives me an error. "Products is a variable but use like a Type"

Comment: Try this..       
            
return products.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToList();

Comment: This is an elaborate comment, not an answer I'm afraid.

Comment: That's why it's not marked as an answer.

Comment: It shouldn't have been posted as an answer in the first place. This is not a forum.

Comment: Okay, my bad, sorry.

Comment: No problem, you now have enough reputation to post comments. :) Try that next time, you asked pretty good questions that would help clarify what the OP actually is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks on the guidance. Will do :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IList<Products> GetProducts()
{
    var products = new List<Products>()
    {
        new Products { ID="1",Name="Soap",Price="200"},
        new Products { ID="2",Name="Trouser",Price="300"},
        new Products { ID="3",Name="Shirt",Price="400"}
    }.ToList();

    return products;
}
```

The return type should be `IList<Products>`, not `IList<System.Type>`.

Comment: No, I have to return a T type list. That is a requirement.